# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ObjectId [0]

Tags: java, bson

I'm getting an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ObjectId [0] when I try to do similar to the code below in one of my class.

```
    String s = "0_abc";
--------
private ObjectId obj; [Instance variable]
public NewClass(String s){
    String[] sarray = s.split("_");
    obj = new ObjectId(sarray[0]);
}
```

What could be the possible reason for it to fail?

Comment: Thats not valid syntax... What are you trying to do with your third line? If its to create a new ObjectID using the 0th element of sarray, you need to use normal parentheses, not the curly ones. ie. ( and )

Comment: Oops...sorry! Changed it!

Comment: Post your ObjectId class definition here - after that we can give you better suggestions

Comment: Here, obj is an instance variable and s is the parameter that is passed to the constructor of the class and that is where obj gets set.

Answer (score 4):

I assume ObjectId class is (org.bson.types.ObjectId) and it is used in the MongoDB Java driver.
What this exception means is that "0" cannot be pass as a value for the ObjectId construction.

Not every string is a correct ObjectId value. When ObjectId is initialized with the given string, validation is done. For example ObjectId requires string to have 24 characters. There are more constrains and you can find the complete validation source code [in GitHub repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java), in the method isValid().

If you want to create an ObjectId object with correct value you can create it using available factory method like this:

```
ObjectId obj = ObjectId.get()
```

This will create ObjectId with auto-generated value.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have not sent the stacktrace but I think that the exception is thrown from constructor of your class `ObjectId` that does not allow sending `0` as an argument.

Comment: Does it throw this exception when the argument is 0 in any other case?